# Multiple many-to-many associations in one Grails domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I am using Grails 3.0.6 and am struggling with a complicated and highly interconnected domain model. I have classes with multiple many-to-many associations to other classes and I am left with no choice but to have multiple belongsTo associations on at least one class. I am unable to figure out the syntax to represent this.

My domain model was quite complicated, but I was able to reduce my problem to this simplified example:

```
class Graph {
    static hasMany = [vertices: Vertex]
}

class OtherClass {
    static hasMany = [vertices: Vertex]
}

class Vertex {
    static hasMany = [graph: Graph, other: OtherClass]
}
```

In this simplified example, I could get around the problem by declaring the ownership between the domain classes on Graph and OtherClass... In my complicated domain model, I don't have this choice because there are too many classes with multiple many-to-many associations.

I have tried this:

```
class Vertex {
    static hasMany = [graphs: Graph, others: OtherClass]
    static belongsTo = Graph, OtherClass
}
```

but I get an NPE.

I have tried this:

```
class Vertex {
    static hasMany = [graphs: Graph, others: OtherClass]
    static belongsTo = [graphs: Graph, others: OtherClass]
}
```

but I still get "GrailsDomainException: No owner defined between domain classes [Graph] and [Vertex]"

Is there something I could do with mappedBy to correctly represent this?

In many of my many-to-many associations, cascading saves are not actually wanted (although they won't hurt), so I don't need belongsTo (or an "owner") for that purpose. This makes me wonder if associations on the domain classes are really how I should be modeling these relationships. Is there something else I could be doing?

Comment: Consider explicitly mapping the join tables with domain classes like in the spring-security-core `UserRole` class.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith You are talking about this, right? https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/f7c741e6507b068b6d6a8d168d9f69fc96269760/src/docs/guide/domainClasses/personAuthorityClass.gdoc   I've seen something like that done before. If I create a class called VertexGraph, will that map to the join table? Does VertexGraph vs GraphVertex matter?

Comment: Right - it's a big less convenient, but you get a lot more control (and no performance issues due to collections). Some criteria queries don't work when using this approach, but I can help with any specific issues

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I was able to get my toy example working with your suggestion-- see my answer below. Is that sorta what you were thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

per Burt Beckwith's comment, I created an additional domain class to represent the join table. Now, one many-to-many association is broken down into two one-to-many associations and the problem does not arise.

Example:

```
class Graph {
    static hasMany = [graphVertexRelations: GraphVertexRelation]
}

class OtherClass {
    static hasMany = [vertices: Vertex]
}

class Vertex {
    static hasMany = [graphVertexRelations: GraphVertexRelation, others: OtherClass]
    static belongsTo = OtherClass
}

class GraphVertexRelation {
    static belongsTo = [graph: Graph, vertex: Vertex]

    static GraphVertexRelation create(Graph graph, Vertex vertex, boolean flush = false) {
        new GraphVertexRelation(graph: graph, vertex: vertex).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would remove the `hasMany` and `belongsTo` properties and manage everything from the join class to avoid the unnecessary performance overhead of the collections. See [this talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) for more info

Answer (score 0):

The exception that you're seeing `"GrailsDomainException: No owner defined between domain classes [Graph] and [Vertex]"` means that the ORM can't figure out what the base class is, and there is a cyclical relationship between Graph and Vertex.

If you want to maintain the relationship to see what Graph a Vertex is in, you can do a backwards lookup using a criteria.

```
class Graph {
    static hasMany = [vertices: Vertex]
}

class OtherClass {
    static hasMany = [vertices: Vertex]
}

class Vertex {
    static transients = ['graphs']
    static hasMany = [other: OtherClass]

    List<Graph> getGraphs() {
        // Backwards link, using the graph table
        Graph.withCriteria() {
            vertices {
                inList("id", [this.id.toLong()])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I truly need a many-to-many relationship. If I understand transients correctly, this is creating a one-to-many relationship between Graph and Vertex. I need the Vertex to be able to be in multiple Graphs.

Comment: Okay. It's your data model and you obviously have non-listed constraints. Given that you have no attributes in the 'Vertex' class at all though, I assumed that you may not the need to have the same exact Vertex instance in a graph, when you could just use shared information in the OtherClass(s). P.S. You should most likely not store your graph object in the relational database for performance reasons using most graph algorithms.