# Grails - Multiple Many-to-Many via Custom Join Tables w/ Cascade Delete & Same Class w/o belongsTo

Tags: database, grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

I'm building a CRM System and want to normalize my database. The following fields are used by many Domain Classes/DB Tables such as Employee, Contact, Lead, etc:

- Address
- PhoneNumber
- EmailAddress
- SocialNetwork
- ReviewSite

The Employee Domain Class/DB Table belongs to my User domain class in a 1-to-1 relationship. In addition to the fact that an employee can have many phone numbers, email address, etc., they can also have both a many-to-many relationship and a one-to-many relationship with the Team Domain Class such that Employees are 'Team Leads' & 'Team Members' of many different teams, while teams have many different members and only one leader.

My question is what is the best way to handle these myriad relationships within Grails. There are answers to each piece of my question, but they almost always run into issues when employed in parallel.

According to Burt Beckwith, the best solution is to manually create join tables for each relationship and manage them without the use of hasMany; however, this solution is not demonstrated anywhere. There is also a lack of quality documentation explaining this issues (which is arguably the most difficult part of Grails to grasp).

Can someone provide a solution to this more complex problem that explains how the smaller piecewise solutions referenced fit together?

Here is a sample Domain Model Demonstrating what I want to accomplish:

```
class Employee {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    ...
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    //Custom Pivot Tables or HasMany?
    static hasMany = [teams: Employee_Team, emails: Email, socialNetworks: SocialNetwork, ...]
}


class Team {
    String name
    ...
    static hasMany = [employees: Employee_Team]
}

class Employee_Team {

    static belongsTo = [employee: Employee, team: Team]

    static Employee_Team create(Employee employee, Team team, boolean flush = false) {
    new Employee_Team(employee: employee, team: team).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }
}

class EmailAddress {
    def email
    ...
    static hasOne = [owner: ????, leadContact: Lead, ...]
    ???? could be a Customer, Employee, Company, etc.
}

class SocialNetwork {
    String name
    ...
    static hasMany = [employees: Employee, customers: Customer, leads: Lead, ...]
}
```

https://chrisbroadfoot.id.au/2008/07/19/many-to-many-relationship-mapping-with-gorm-grails/

[Multiple many-to-many associations in one Grails domain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873388/multiple-many-to-many-associations-in-one-grails-domain-class)

EDIT:

In repsonse to vahid's understandable misunderstanding of my use case. First, the details aren't important. I just think using foo, bar, etc. here would have obstructed clarity. Second, I've normalized phone numbers and email addresses into their own table, because I don't want to restrict people to a finite number of phone numbers (AKA Primary, Secondary OR Work, Personal) AND I have many tables that require phone number, email address, etc. fields. For example, employees (platform users), contacts (people in other company's), company's (office main lines), leads, opportunities, and customers all require contact info; A lead might be associated with 3 contacts (with multiple personal numbers) at the target company (with multiple offices, departments, and/or main lines) and need to store multiple numbers for the employees (SDR, Account Executive and Solutions Architect) working on the lead's demo. Hard coding fields to fit all use cases would be impossible. Lastly, I'm building a Neural Network that models the relationships between data points and social networks to perform classification and predictive modeling. Therefore, I need to be able to trace a number back to its owner as well as parse out all the adjunct relationships connected to that number (possibly across multiple SASS instances). The point is, there are valid reasons for needing support for multiple bi-directional GORM mappings w/ cascade delete involving a single table. However, I've yet to see a quality example of this executed in Grails. In Laravel for example it's simple, because many-to-many relationships don't require an "owner" (belongsTo mapping). Note: I updated the EmailAddress Domain Class to HasOne, but this Domain Class would also need other many-to-many mappings not shown above. Additionally, I think that change prevents me from mapping a conference call dial in number to multiple employees.

Comment: I have removed my answer since you are suggesting you are going to downvote it. Even though it was intended to make you try and see differently to how you have received requirements and appear to demand that this must be the way it should work. As i suggested and still stick with what i said, personally see no benefit of employee having many emails and then emails having many employees. You can do a query from employee to work this out if required. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nofscHeEuU this may be of help to you.